# Larvel foreach with pivot

Tags: php, laravel

I have a many to many relation with a pivot

Tourney Model

```
public function teams()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\APP\Team\Team', 'team_tourney')->withPivot('status')->withTimestamps();
    }
```

Team Model

```
public function tourneys()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\APP\Tourney\Tourney', 'team_tourney')->withPivot('status')->withTimestamps();
    }
```

User Model

```
public function tourneys()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\APP\Tourney\Tourney');
    }

public function teams()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\APP\Team\Team');
    }
```

Controller show function:

```
$tourney = Tourney::with('user', 'teams')->where('slug', $slug)->first();

$teams = Team::with('tourneys')->where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)->get();
```

In my view I need to first get a list of the users teams. Then check if the Tourney Teams contains the any of the Users Teams and list them.

```
@foreach($teams as $team)
  {{-- List teams if already attached --}}
  @if($tourney->teams->contains($team))

     {{-- Get TourneyTeam status --}}
     @foreach($tourney->teams as $tourneyTeam)
        <p>{{$tourneyTeam->pivot->status}}</p>
     @endforeach

                           
   @endif
@endforeach
```

When doing this I get the status printed out twice. Example, 11 is returned instead of 1

I assume this is because I have a loop within a loop. How can I adjust this to only return the status once.

Comment: You have three models  here, `User`, `Team`, and `Tourney`. Please provide the relationships between all three models. What you've got here makes it look like each team can have only a single user.

Comment: Ok I updated with User model

Comment: Because a user can have many teams. A team belongs to a user. A tourney can have many teams. Team can belong to many tourneys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this by creating another query and adding that as a blade derivative.

Blade derivative

```
Blade::if('teamTourneyStatus', function($tourney, $team){
            
     $team = $tourney->teams->where('id', $team->id)->first();
        if($team->pivot->status == 1){
            return true;
        }
            return false;
                       
});
```

Updated view

```
@foreach($teams as $team)
  {{-- List teams if already attached --}}
  @if($tourney->teams->contains($team))

     {{-- Get TourneyTeam status --}}
     @teamTourneyStatus($tourney, $team) "show if true" @endteamTourneyStatus
                   
   @endif
@endforeach
```